# Git server doesn't show latest pushed files casually

Tags: git, ubuntu, unix

I have created my own git server on a ubuntu cloud server.

I pushed a file called second.txt.

on my server i have the following

[image]

so with

```
git-ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAD
```

it shows all files on the branch.
but how is it possible to also see them with pure ls "physically" on my working directory.

so that i may be able to copy the files elsewhere.

Iam on master branch and pushed to master branch.

Answer (score 2):

In a remote git, the working tree does not automatically reflect what's in the repo every time the repo changes by being pushed to.

(In fact, in a remote git, there is usually no working tree at all! And when there is one, you cannot, by default, push to the branch that is currently checked out.)

So you could try (in your ssh connection) `git checkout master` and then `ls`. But in general the fact that you see *anything* in your remote working tree seems like a bug in your setup already. A repo that is functioning as a remote repo should be a bare repo! If you want to copy something out of the repo, do *not* check out a branch; just copy the file out with `git show`.